# Google Analytics Event Label count is not increasing

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a GTM tag that pushes a dataLayer with events to GA.
I am recording add to cart button click and the item number.
When 1st time say Item number is "item1" and clicking on add to cart button, it works fine and GTM fires GA tag and data is recorded in GA.
When I again click on "Add to Cart" with the same  Item number that is "item1", count in next to Event Label is not increasing. New values are recorded but existing values count is not increased. Am I missing something ? Below is my custom HTNL which pushes to dataLayer.

```
<script>  
var callback = function(event){
var itemnum = document.getElementById("itemnumber").value.trim();
if(itemnum ){  
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
window.dataLayer.push({
 event: 'CartClick',
 eventAction: 'Added',
 eventCategory: 'cATEGORY',
 eventLabel: itemnum 
   });
}  
};
var cartIcon = document.querySelector('add-to-cart');
cartIcon .addEventListener('click',callback,true);
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Check itemnum value with console.log inside condition, it is 1 or the actual value?

Comment: its the actual item's value. not the count